# Why is my jquery selector returning undefined?

Tags: jquery, meteor, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

Im using jasmine to do unit testing for my meteor app, and one of my test is to test that a DOM Element has been hidden. But when using jQuery to select that Dom it returns undefined thus failing my tests.

Jasmine test:

```
it("should filter all cards by single tag", function(){
      event = jasmine.createSpyObj("event",["target","preventDefault"]);
      event = {
        target: {
          thoughts : {value: "testThought"},
          tags: {value: "testTag"},
          author: {value: "testAuthor"},
          goodCategoryRadio: {checked: true},
          badCategoryRadio: {checked: false}
        },
        preventDefault: function(){}
      };
      spyOn(Session, "get").and.returnValue("testRoom");
      spyOn(Session, "set");
      var baseTime = new Date();
      jasmine.clock().mockDate(baseTime);

      Template.card.fireEvent("submit #card");
      event = {
        target: {
          thoughts : {value: "testThought"},
          tags: {value: "different tag"},
          author: {value: "testAuthor"},
          goodCategoryRadio: {checked: true},
          badCategoryRadio: {checked: false}
        },
        preventDefault: function(){}
      };
      baseTime = new Date();
      jasmine.clock().mockDate(baseTime);

      Template.card.fireEvent("submit #card");
      tagEvent = jasmine.createSpyObj("event",["toElement.innerHTML"]);
      tagEvent = {
        toElement: { value: "<tag class='tag'>testTag</tag>"}
      };
      Template.room.fireEvent("click tag", {event: tagEvent});
      expect($("div#card").eq(1).is(":visible")).toBeVisible();
      expect($("div#card").eq(0).is(":visible")).toBeHidden();
    });
```

Comment: You're second expectation is expecting something which is visible to be hidden... it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also are you sure these queries are running against something that is part of an actual DOM, and not something in memory?

Comment: my second expect i the element that should be hidden based off the selected filter and the first expect is the element that is visible because its not affected by the filter. the div#card are dynamically added to an html dom from Meteor if that makes a difference

Comment: If you're expecting something to be hidden, how can you select it with `:visible` selector? Since it is hidden it won't return any results.

Comment: the .is(":visible") return true or false based on if its visible